# Making the title uppercase and centering

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, chapters

I want to make my Chapter title uppercase and in the center of the page.
this is mine

```
\documentclass[12pt,TimesNewRoman,a4paper,oneside,onecolumn]{purnamiReport}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}
\usepackage{epsf,epsfig,amsmath,amsthm,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym,graphicx,amssymb,multirow,url}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{Chapter1}
\include{Chapter2}
\include{Chapter3}
\include{Chapter4}
\include{Chapter5}
```

My friend use the same command but she has different output. Hers is in uppercase model...

What should I do?
Thank you

Comment: The formatting of the chapters is most likely handeled in the documentclass 'purnamiReport', which I can not find online. Try to comment-out the titlesec package '% \usepackage{titlesec}' and check if your output changes. For more in-depth changes, one would need to know what hapens in the documentclass file

Answer (score 2):

As said by  Martin H. in his comment, the formatting of your titles is likely modified by the class. In the opposite case (standard titles) you could comment out `titlesec` and use the `\patchcmd` command of package `etoolbox` with, for example:

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\raggedright}{\centering}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\@chapapp\space}{\space}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries\thechapter\space--\space}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\@M \Huge \bfseries #1}{\@M\Huge\bfseries\sffamily\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}{}
 \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\par\nobreak\vskip 20\p@}{}{}   
\makeatother
```

very close to what I currently use for my courses:
[image]